Hot-swappable battery in series
I'm trying to figure out a circuit to power a robot with multiple BLDC actuators, with two 6-cell LiPo batteries and would need some advice on safety and possible power switching. Please pardon my roughness here and there, I haven't designed circuits in maybe 10 years.
The two batteries should be connected in series, giving a total of roughly 50V when fully charged. The robot should not be powered off to exchange the battery, so a hot-swap mechanism is necessary. I was thinking of attaching an LED to each battery connector on the robot side in parallel to allow for this. The motors are fine getting powered from a single battery, as they will not be moving, just holding torque. In parallel to the motors, the batteries also power a PC and control electronics, through a DC/DC converter with its own power switch.
The actuators should be connected to the batteries through a smart switch, which should allow for current to flow back from the motors to the battery for regenerative breaking. The regenerative breaking will not happen during the hot-swap (when only a single battery would be connected). There will be a lot of peak power involved, which the switch would need to tolerate (tens to hundreds of Amps in bursts).
I drew-up a very rough schematic to get the idea through:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Obviously there will be a lot of current involved, also inrush currents on power-on, so I want to avoid sparks while connecting the batteries. I assume this simple diode idea might not suffice, also I have no idea for the smart switch (I used a BTS555 in previous designs, which will not fit in here), and this is where I am asking for advice, pointing me in the right direction, or maybe even solutions which already exist?
EDIT: Sorry for not using the in-built schematic editor - fixed that

The site has an built in schematic editor. Draw your 'very rough schematic' directly in your post. It's more polite than asking potential answers to follow a link, especially if that link behaves strangely as it did for me - I could see the circuit briefly, then it vanished.

And people like me will not even click on a link to an unknown site, it's pointless since the question will be useless whenever that link goes down or is removed in the future.
